# Why does Django throw ImproperlyConfigured when I try to import in the Python shell?

Tags: python, django

This one kept throwing me when I started Django. Suppose you have a project `project` with an app `app`, and you want to inspect it. So you import parts of it in the Python shell:

```
(virtualenv) $ PYTHONPATH=. python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import project.app.views
(...cut traceback...)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS,
but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Fine. So you set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`:

```
(virtualenv) $ PYTHONPATH=. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.project.settings python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import project.app.views
(...cut traceback...)
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

with no explanation as to what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

1. Set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `project.project.settings` (where `project` is the name of your project)
2. In the Python shell, `import django; django.setup()` as the first thing you do.

So, for example:

```
(virtualenv) $ PYTHONPATH=. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.project.settings python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django; django.setup()
>>> import project.app.views
```

All good!